# How to create a UIImage from bytes

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I've a `String` with byte code of a Image, I want create a `UIImage` from it.

My data is like below:

```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```

And I try to do this:

```
let data = Data(base64Encoded: codeBytes)
cell.imgView.image = UIImage(data: data)
```

But this returns nil.

This is my code that use this resource:
where `String(listaDados[indexPath.row]["image_small"] as! String` is the object of my byte code of image.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellProduct") as! TableViewCellProduct

if String(listaDados[indexPath.row]["image_small"] as! String) != "" {
    let data = Data(base64Encoded: String(listaDados[indexPath.row]["image_small"] as! String))
    cell.imgView.image = UIImage(data: data)
} 
else {
    print("Nao tem imagem")
}

cell.labelName.text = (listaDados[indexPath.row]["name"] as! String)
return cell
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.

```
let data : Data = Data(base64Encoded: codeBytes, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)!
cell.imgView.image = UIImage(data: data)
```

**Output Image**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try removing new-line characters. I tried below code and it worked.

```
let anImageString = "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0aHBwgJC4nICIsIxwcKDcpLDAxNDQ0Hyc5PTgyPC4zNDL/2wBDAQkJCQwLDBgNDRgyIRwhMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjL/wAARCABAAEADASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3+Pn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD3+iiopp1gALg4PcUJXAloqut7A/Rqk+0Rf38fUYp2YrklFRfaIi2A2foM0vnR5wXAPoeKLMdySikDK3RgfoaWkAVma0+y1B9606x/EJIskx13VUdxPYp2zl1GVyParjvkx43KWUAnjPU+tZdr9zkVad9ph7jaOD9TWjJMnTNS+26C15qFqLuWCeZNkEIZmKsF+Vc9cGtJdetreFUOm6pFGP8ApxchRn2z61z+kmKOwmD25lA1S8C44x84rpYZBPHH5R8lyf4o2fPt1GKTVwFk1jTBLLE9ysTxOY2M0bRru54DMAG6djWxZ824+p/nWJHeyeV5cqyZxyy4x+RY1s6ec2i5OTk8n60pbDW5arE8SNi1jA/vf4Vt15/8TfFcPhlNOWW0kuftRfAjmEZXbg55Bz1pU4uUrLcJSUVeWxp2eMYLLj2rQKwtGjPjgAZ3ds14sPi3aRNkaHcH63i//E1KPjVAoH/EknGP+nxP/iK39hU7fkZqtTfU9A8P+W+m3LhA6nUrtlB/3x61src7GVvs06KByFjU5/EGvMvD3jS4/sTTYbTSDc3F891c4a8SMIPO28krz0qw3izWJHQroSfOQqn+04iOTjqU4qOR/wBNF8y/pM9GW4jIKrbThevEWB/OtrSz/omB2YivH4/GmqRoZ/7GhKDg/wDE1hHP/fI/WvRfAWvjxFoEt59m+zMly8LxecsuCoH8S8d6mUXa/wCqGpK9jdl02GYcy3S/7lzIv8mrJvvBOh6p5f8AaVu995efL+1yGUpnGcFs46CuhorNSa2HZHI/8Kx8H/8AQDtP+/K/4Up+GXg8qQdDtMEY4iUfyFdbRT55dwsjlE+G3hJLaG2/saCSGAMIll+fYGYsQC2SOSTTh8N/Bw/5l6wP1hFdTRRzS7hZHNL8PfCC/wDMu6cfrAprY03SNP0aBoNNs4rWFm3GOJdq59cdKu0UnJvdhZH/2Q=="
let anImageData = Data(base64Encoded: anImageString)
let anImage = UIImage(data: anImageData!)
Swift.print(anImage)

// Output
// Optional(<UIImage: 0x6000000ae580>, {64, 64})
```